# Determine response entity length

Tags: java, spring, exception

Here I'm calling api to fill specifc data on it , I'm using `HTTP post` request with `JPA`, I'm getting trouble sometimes the response is too large `value too large for column`, I made a small lookeup to check from response size but my problem here each time the lookup will check from from length of response body,
is there any idea to handle it with excption once it throws ?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AutoDialerApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AutoDialerApplication.class);
    @Autowired

    private Bulk_repositoryRepository bulk_repositoryRepository;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AutoDialerApplication.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.setBasicAuth("user", "pass");

        while(true) {
            //Convert to Oracle Date Format
            SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date currentDate = new Date();
            String strDate = sdfDate.format(currentDate);
            // dateTwoDaysAgo..
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -3);
            Date dateTwoDaysAgo = cal.getTime();

            logger.info("Just Started"); 
            for (Bulk_repository churnss : bulk_repositoryRepository.findAllByStatusAndCampTypeAndCampStartDateBetween(0,2,dateTwoDaysAgo,currentDate)) {
                System.out.print(churnss);
                logger.info(churnss.toString());
                BulkAutoDialer AddOffer = new BulkAutoDialer(strDate,"1", churnss.getParam1(),churnss.getMsisdn());

                logger.info(AddOffer.toString());
                HttpEntity<BulkAutoDialer> entity = new HttpEntity<BulkAutoDialer>(AddOffer,headers);

                ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                        "https ...", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);

                if(responseEntity.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK){
                    String response = responseEntity.getBody();
                    System.out.println(response);
                    if(responseEntity.getBody().length() < 3 ) {
                    churnss.setFulfilment_status(response);
                    }else {
                        churnss.setFulfilment_status(" \"-10\" ");
                    }
                    churnss.setStatus(1);
                    churnss.setProcessDate(new Date());
                    logger.info(churnss.toString() + ", Response: " + response);
                    bulk_repositoryRepository.save(churnss);
                }else {
                    logger.warn("Record Id: " + churnss.getId() + ", Http Failed Response: " + responseEntity.getStatusCode());
                }
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }

}
```

here my loopkup :

```
if(responseEntity.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK){
  String response = responseEntity.getBody();
  System.out.println(response);
  if(responseEntity.getBody().length() < 3 ) {
  churnss.setFulfilment_status(response);
 }else {
 churnss.setFulfilment_status(" \"-10\" ");
                        }
 churnss.setStatus(1);
 churnss.setProcessDate(new Date());
 logger.info(churnss.toString() + ", Response: " + response);
 bulk_repositoryRepository.save(churnss);
```

Comment: You're confusing unrelated things. "value too large for column" has nothing to do with the size of an HTTP response. It's an error coming from your database and telling you that you're trying to save a value that is too large (for example, 10 characters long) for the defined length of that column (for example: varchar(9)).

Comment: yes i handle the problem from root cuase , but here i make a lookup to check body response , is there anyway to implement as excption once it throws without make a lookpu with if statment ?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't figure out what you're trying to say.

Comment: @NikolanAsad I think I know what you mean.  You should know the maximum size of your column.  so you can check it immidately with either responseEntity.getHeader("Content-length") > MAX_COLUMN_SIZE_OF_THIS_COLUMNG or by checking it against the length of the returned string.

Comment: @JBNizet , i just want  to create a exception handler for `'if(responseEntity.getBody().length() < 3 ) {..` instead of using normal if statment that check every time from the response entity body , i think normal excption with check once it throw , sorry for my english dear